# Laravel: How to return view() with ->withInput()

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

How am I able to return view('support') with following:

```php
->withInput()
->with('success', 'Found results');
```

Code

```php
  // if validation do not fail
        if ($validated->fails() === false) {
            //session()->flashInput($request->input());
            // return
            return view('siteadmin.support.support', [
                'articles' => $articles,
                'categories' => $categories,
            ]);
        }
```

Following code is not working:
Code

```php
  // if validation do not fail
        if ($validated->fails() === false) {
            //session()->flashInput($request->input());
            // return
            return view('siteadmin.support.support', [
                'articles' => $articles,
                'categories' => $categories,
            ])
            ->withInput()
            ->with('success', 'Found results');
        }
```

Comment: you want to move to another page after validation fails ?

Comment: what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to return back to the same view with updated variables and old input: 

 'articles' => $articles,
'categories' => $categories
and with old input: ->withInput();

Comment: And I can not use:  return redirect() ->back() as then I am not able to send the two  updated variables back to view: 

'articles' => $articles,
'categories' => $categories

Comment: You can use the `back()` you can use the `old()` helper  inside the value of input

Comment: Yes, but what about sending the two updated variables: 'articles' => $articles, 'categories' => $categories

Comment: `<input value="{{ old('categories') }}">` like this

Comment: Okay I get it so you want to return back with a result ? Something like that ?

Comment: Yes. An updated result for 'articles' => $articles, 'categories' => $categories

Comment: Thats why I want to use retrun view method. But then I am not able to get access to old input and flash message.

Comment: You can pass it in a session instead. `session(['categories'=>$categories, 'articles' => $articles])`

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a `session` you can use `session()` helper or `$request->session->put()`

```
// validation success

session([
    'categories' => $categories,
    'articles' => $articles,
]);

return back();
```

then you can just access the session value in blade using the `session()` helper.

```
<div> {{ session('categories') }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this in multiple ways. Through sessions or through the view. Firstly if you have session messages setup you can throw a message like this

```
$request->session()->flash('success','Found Results'); 
return view('...')->withInput();
```

Or you can pass the success message through the view like

```
return view('siteadmin.support.support', compact('articles', 'categories'), [
   'success' => 'Results Found'
])->withInput();
```

Comment: When I am using ->withInput(); I am getting following error: Undefined array key 0.


I tried both code examples and got the error: Undefined array key 0

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `withInput` method provided by the `RedirectResponse` instance to flash the current request's input data to the session before redirecting the user to a new location. This is typically done if the user has encountered a validation error. Once the input has been flashed to the session, you may easily retrieve it during the next request to repopulate the form:

`return back()->withInput();`

Comment: Thanks. I also tried this option, but then I am not able to return the two new updated variables based on search term: 


articles' => $articles,
'categories' => $categories